# Accessing indexedDB from code inside a Blob

Tags: javascript, blob, google-chrome-devtools, indexeddb, web-worker

First I've to explain the scenario:

- Kiosk web app with CHROMIUM, showing LOCAL webs. That is, no webserver installed. Chromium is always showing "file:///" pages.
- The reason is: sometimes, the computer can be offline (network issues, wifi range...).
- Requirement: we want to use google analytics. When computer is ONLINE, the system send http request to GA normally. When OFFLINE, we want to save http request to indexedDB.
- Using a worker that executes a job each X seconds, we test the Internet connection. If success, the worker gets the http requests saved into indexedDB and send to Google Analytics.

We've achieved all steps, but one: **accesing indexedDB from javascript code inside a Blob**.

The reason to use a js Worker inside a Blob is because Chrome don't allow accesing javascript files when the scenario is locally (File:///). This is a small example of a Worker inside a Blob, that access indexedDb each 3 seconds. The example works great in Firefox, for example. But in Chrome, this exception is launched when executing code that access to indexedDb from Blob code:

> Unhandled rejection: OpenFailedError: SecurityError Failed to execute
>   'open' on 'IDBFactory': access to the Indexed Database API is denied
>   in this context.

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Example error blob and indexeddb</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>This example demostrate that javascript code inside a Blob can't access indexedDb in Chrome.</p>
    <p>Click 'Start WebWorker' to create a Worker inside a Blob. This worker tries to insert some<br>
    data into a database created in 'startWorker()' function.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="startWorker()" id="btnStart">
        Start WebWorker
    </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="stopWorker()" id="btnStop">
        Stop WebWorker
    </button>


  <!-- FOR LOGGING INFO PURPOSES -->
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!-- TRICK !! Declare this block of type 'javascript/worker' or something non-standard.
      Later we can create on the fly javascript executable code
      using a Blob (see 'window.onload' function later on this file)
  -->
  <script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">

        var started = false;
        var timer;

        onmessage = function (event)
        {
            var orden = event.data.toString();

            switch (orden)
            {
                case 'start':
                    start();
                    break;
                case 'stop':
                    stop();
                    break;
                default:
                    notRecognized(orden);
                    break;
            }
        }

        function start()
        {
            if( ! started)
            {
              timer = setInterval(function(){ job() }, 3000);
              started = true;
            }
        }

        function stop()
        {
            if(started)
            {
                clearInterval(timer);
                started = false;
            }
        }

        //Executed each 3 seconds (see start() )
        function job()
        {
          // Open the database -> ERROR!! Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'IDBFactory':
          //                              access to the Indexed Database API is denied in this context.
          var open = indexedDB.open("MyDatabase", 1);

          open.onsuccess = function()
          {
              // Start a new transaction
              var db = open.result;
              var tx = db.transaction("MyObjectStore", "readwrite");
              var store = tx.objectStore("MyObjectStore");
              var index = store.index("NameIndex");

              // Add some data
              store.put({id: 12345, name: {first: "John", last: "Doe"}, age: 42});
              store.put({id: 67890, name: {first: "Bob", last: "Smith"}, age: 35});

              // Close the db when the transaction is done
              tx.oncomplete = function()
              {
                  db.close();
              };
          }
        }//end job()

        function notRecognized(orden)
        {
            var mensaje = 'Comando no reconocido';
            selt.postMessage(mensaje + ': ' + orden);
        }
  </script>






    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myWorker;
        var workerStarted = false;

        //Al cargar la pagina, se llama al onload, que carga el WebWorker
        window.onload = function () {

            var blob = new Blob([ document.querySelector('#worker').textContent ], {type : 'text/javascript'});

            myWorker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

            myWorker.onmessage = function (event)
            {
                document.getElementById("demo").textContent = event.data; //cambiamos el texto del <p>
                console.log("Got: " + event.data + "\n");
            };

            myWorker.onerror = function (error)
            {
                document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Worker error: " + error.message;
                console.log("Worker error: " + error.message + "\n");
                throw error;
            };
        };//e onload

      //click en botón iniciar, mandamos 'start' al worker
      function startWorker()
      {
         if(workerStarted)
         {
            document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Worker yet started !";
            return;
          }


          //Create the DataBase
          var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

          // Open (or create) the database
          var open = indexedDB.open("MyDatabase", 1);

          // Create the schema
          open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
              var db = open.result;
              var store = db.createObjectStore("MyObjectStore", {keyPath: "id"});
              var index = store.createIndex("NameIndex", ["name.last", "name.first"]);
          };

          workerStarted = true;

          //Start Worker
          myWorker.postMessage('start');
      }

      //click en botón parar, mandamos 'stop' al worker
      function stopWorker() {
          myWorker.postMessage('stop');
      }
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to the Indexed Database API is denied in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805775/access-to-the-indexed-database-api-is-denied-in-this-context)

Comment: The same problem, but no explanation about the detail that the code launch the exception is "stored" into the Blob. That's the key. The answer in the other post is not possible in or scenario (local files, no web server)

Comment: As I tested, if you put the file into a web server, it works well, if you open the file as file:/// the error will come out. I think this is because the file:/// blob: provide a null origin which is not allowed to operate indexedDB